# Efficient way for updating data in a data table from another data table

Tags: c#, datatable, performance

I have a data table in my ASP.NET web service project, this data table has around 500K records in it with 39 columns and is present in Cache.
After a minute a background thread hits the database and brings update records from database, which I want to update in the Cached data table, I am using following approach but it is taking good enough time to do it:

```
foreach (DataRow dRNew in dtNew.Rows)
{
     DataRow row = dtOriginal.Select("ID=" + dRNew["ID"]).First();
     row["Column1"] = dRNew["Column1"];
     row["Column2"] = dRNew["Column2"];
     row["Column3"] = dRNew["Column3"];
}
```

I have replaced the following line:

```
DataRow row = dtOriginal.Select("ID=" + dRNew["ID"]).First();
```

with

```
DataRow row = dtOriginal.AsEnumerable().Where(r => ((Int64)r["ID"]).Equals(dRNew["ID"])).First();
```

but in vain, it is taking like around 5 minutes on my laptop.

Can anyone please guide my where and what am I doing wrong? With which approach can I do it efficiently, I am not sure if `Dataset.Merge` or some other approach can be used.

Comment: SCNR ... `[...] data table [...] 500K records in it with 39 columns and is present in Cache` made me laugh hard immediately... data table + cache + foreach + multithreading + ... **bloody awesome**! you must be chuck norris ...

Comment: :) Might be its funny for you but in my case it is like so, so lets laugh hard together :D

Comment: actually I do laugh because the env you are hunting down _really_ hurts ... within this scenario there ain't a performant/practicable solution. i would rather start with a basic question: why do you have to store the values somewhere? what are you doing? give us a bigger picture! ...

Comment: If I put a 1GB RAM on server only for this Caching thing, i don't think so that its going to hurt. So what do you suggest to replace this damn data table with? Querying database is not an option for me.

Comment: you misunderstood _hurt_: it's like watching a guy, with hardly any knowledge on DST, UTC, ..., implementing a very clever-clever system for such tasks. someone should jump right in and say "no" - that's what i've tried to achieve with my questions (which you haven't answered yet). i can not (and do not want to) give any advices yet - first of all i need answers! (one true option would be: why not use a static `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, where `TValue` might be your PK-type and `TValue` the other 38 columns). btw: if you think adding RAM would help, go for it!

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your point. Well the story is that on a page in our application, we are showing a dojo grid and 2 charts, the data for the grid was being retrieved from database, but there were JOINS of like 25 tables involved in it and Stored procedure was taking time like 12-15 secs, so we came across a solution to put the data in Cache through background thread and than present it to user after getting it from Cache. This solution is working fine except the above problem. I hope I answered you question.

Comment: `so we came across a solution to put the data in Cache through background thread and than present it to user after getting it from Cache.` you might not know it, but this is a simple repository-domain-pattern (repo-pattern: http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=249 + singleton data-container) only realized with the limper aka data-table. I further assume that you are polling the data every minute and want to merge newly created or updated rows to the cache-instance - am I right?

Comment: Thanks for this new knowledge for me, I am going to go through this blog, Yeh you are right, after every minute we are fetching new or updated rows.

Comment: it would be better if you centralize your data-access: read **AND** write should be done over a repo, so the polling becomes obsolete. after this you are all set, can use freaky funky linq-queries, ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way

```
dtOriginal.Merge(dtNew);
```

Comment: why take a copy rather than just dtOriginal.Merge(dtNew)?

Comment: @MAfifi sorry I just gave quick example that you achieve it by these methods already available, please use in the order whats suitable for you code

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, the only problem I faced was, Merge statement was adding new rows in the table, which I figured out that If I put a Primary Key in my data table, it will solve the problem.

Comment: Can you do a .Merge if one of the tables has no primary key?

Comment: @Imran Balouch 
You need to specify the primary key of the table before merging in order to achieve the required results

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, [DataRowCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk.aspx).  Assuming you're DataTable is set correctly, it will be O(log(n)) rather than O(N) which it currently is.

```
foreach (DataRow dRNew in dtNew.Rows) 
{
     DataRow row = null;
     try
     {
         row = dtOriginal.Find(dRNew["ID"]);
     }
     catch (MissingPrimaryKeyException)
     {
         row = dtOriginal.Select("ID=" + dRNew["ID"]).First();
     }
     if (row != null)
     {
         row["Column1"] = dRNew["Column1"]; 
         row["Column2"] = dRNew["Column2"]; 
         row["Column3"] = dRNew["Column3"]; 
     }
}
```

Comment: please ... do not forget about the outer `foreach`. maybe rather a join in a dataset?

Comment: That's essentially what Merge does.

Comment: yes and no ... there should get only 3 out of 39 columns updated - so essentially not a _real_ merge

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that using this would be much quicker:

```
TableToUpdate.AsEnumerable().Join
(
    TableToUpdateFrom.AsEnumerable(),
    lMaster => lMaster["COMMON_FIELD"], lChild => lChild["COMMON_FIELD"],
    (lMaster, lChild) => new { lMaster, lChild }
    ).ToList().ForEach
(
o =>
{
    o.lMaster.SetField("FIELD_TO_BE_UPDATED1", o.lChild["FIELD_TO_BE_UPDATED_FROM1"].ToString());
    o.lMaster.SetField("FIELD_TO_BE_UPDATED2", o.lChild["FIELD_TO_BE_UPDATED_FROM2"].ToString());
    o.lMaster.SetField("FIELD_TO_BE_UPDATED3", o.lChild["FIELD_TO_BE_UPDATED_FROM3"].ToString());
    o.lMaster.SetField("FIELD_TO_BE_UPDATED_ETC", o.lChild["APPROVAL_SCORE_FROM_ETC"].ToString());
}
);
```

Comment: HI Naelem,Can you please tell me how to give two condition in this LINQ..exactly in above code ,how to add another common field?